# Getting spark2 cluster metrics using prometheus jmxexporter

Tags: apache-spark, prometheus, jmx-exporter

We are trying to fetch the spark metrics using prometheus. we are using jmx exporter jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar.

We are able to get the metrics for deploy-mode client but for cluster we are not able to get it.

For standalone command used is

./spark-submit  --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-javaagent:../jars/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar=8071:../conf/spark.yml" --class somecustomeclass --deploy-mode client --executor-memory 3g  --driver-memory 3G ../jars/somejar.jar

For cluster we tried

./spark-submit --supervise --deploy-mode cluster --conf 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-javaagent:jars/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar=8060:/conf/spark.yml spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-javaagent:/jars/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar=8061:/conf/spark.yml spark.jars=/jars/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar ' --files /jars/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkTC --master spark://host1:7077,host2:7077 --executor-memory 1G --total-executor-cores 1  /spark/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.0.jar 1

Are we missing anything in setup or command?

Answer (score 0):

Need to open the jmx ports which was missing in setup..

followed https://argus-sec.com/monitoring-spark-prometheus/ and could get metrics.